# Codeigniter: Run code only if in certain view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to add a 3rd party script (Optimizely) to my  so I want to drop it in to my main template.

However, I only want it to run on one page, my /order page. How can I add this script to the head so that it checks, if View = Order then include this js file, otherwise, don't include it?

Comment: You probably meant to say order controller instead of view. Right?

Answer (score 0):

While loading the view, send it an additional variable having controller name.

In the view, then you can check if the variable's value is order, then you can echo the script.

Code will roughly look like this:

```
// in your controller
$data = array();
// some code that will fill $data
$data['controller'] = get_class($this);
$this->load->view('your_view', $data);

// now, in your view,
if($controller == 'Order')
    echo "<script src='......'></script>";
```